# Cannot remove port from Capybara while visiting external link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Whenever I visit some url from my application then after visiting twitter goes to **"twitter:3000"**
Now I want to remove **:3000** so that in my test case I can visit external link successfully. I have tried several options but its not working. I am using Capybara in Rails

Here is test case

```
test 'z' do
  visit companies_url
  login_twitter
end

def login_twitter
  Capybara.run_server = false
  Capybara.server_port = ''
  Capybara.server_host = 'https://twitter.com'
  visit 'https://twitter.com' #here it goes to **https://twitter.com:3000**
  fill_in 'signin-email', with: 'email@email.com'
  fill_in 'signin-password', 'pass'
  page.find('a', :text => /\ALog in\z/).click
end
```

**application_system_test_case.rb**

```
Capybara.server_port = 3000
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '/home/chromedriver'
driven_by :selenium
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Rails 5.1 system tests, where they've chosen to enable `Capybara.always_include_port = true` which tells Capybara to insert the port it's running the app on in every url visited (unless a non-default port is explicitly specified).  To work around this and directly visit an external site you could do

```
def login_twitter
  Capybara.always_include_port = false  
  visit 'https://twitter.com' #here it goes to **https://twitter.com:3000**
  fill_in 'signin-email', with: 'email@email.com'
  fill_in 'signin-password', 'pass'
  page.find('a', :text => /\ALog in\z/).click
  Capybara.always_include_port = true
end
```

Additionally I'm not sure why you're setting `Capybara.server_port = 3000`, that's generally a bad idea because it prevents you from having your dev instance running while running tests.  It's generally better not to specify a specific `server_port` (let Capybara use a random port) unless you have a genuine need for it (firewall/routing issues).